# sql problem because there are duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle

good morning
I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.cname                                              AS component,
                Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER ()                     AS sum_tipo, 
                Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER (partition BY c.cname) AS sum_by_component 

FROM            jira.jiraissue j, 
                jira.worklog w, 
                jira.project p, 
                jira.issuetype t, 
                jira.component c, 
                jira.nodeassociation na , 
                jira.cwd_user u

WHERE           w.issueid=j.id 
AND             j.project=p.id 
AND             na.source_node_id = j.id 
AND             na.source_node_entity = 'Issue' 
AND             na.sink_node_id=c.id 
AND             t.id=j.issuetype 
And             w.author= u.lower_user_name
AND             w.author in ( select distinct author from jira.worklog where author in (select distinct lower_user_name from jira.cwd_user where display_name in ('Ilanas ejemplo')))   
AND             p.pname=  'Area Económica'  
AND             t.pname= 'Peticion'
AND             w.startdate >='01/01/2018' 
AND             w.startdate <='17/10/2018'
```

I have verified that this query is unbalanced in some small data.

After investigating a little by the tables I have verified the following:

[image]

there should not be rows with same source_node_id (it's user error). I want to do in the sql a distinct or something similar that ne case of having some row with same code only take into account a single row

Comment: you can try by using row_number()

Comment: where i have to put this statement?

Comment: @ilnas your  showed column is not in selection then how you got those column post full query and expected output not image please

Comment: Use the standard `JOIN` notation instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: the image is taken when iwas investigating about the error

Comment: In my work is not permited the use of join

Comment: I personally do not even want to start looking at a query that references 7 tables in the `FROM` with no `JOIN` or `ON` clauses.

Comment: No one knows how I can solve this problem?

Comment: The issue you are having does not look like it is from your query, but from your user inputs. If the double source_no_id is the issue, your data should be fixed in order to solve this issue.

Comment: First question I always ask when people say "I only want to consider 1 of the 'duplicate rows'" is "What row counts and what row gets discarded? What are the rules for this behavior?" -- From there, we can write the SQL to accomplish that. So you have to put your thinking cap on and imagine all possible screwed up scenarios to account for them. I.E. What if there are 3 rows.. what if all 3 rows have the same sink_node_id, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that it can not be done without making some "compromises" about data. 
In your table, it shows that the "duplicate rows" has different sink_node_id (10328 and 10320 or 10326 - not seeing the number correctly).

If you are prepared to make "compromises" here is the query - with the absolute minimal changes of your query - that makes "compromise" that on duplicate chooses the sink_node_id that is maximum in value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.cname                                              AS component,
            Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER ()                     AS sum_tipo, 
            Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER (partition BY c.cname) AS sum_by_component 

 FROM            jira.jiraissue j, 
                 jira.worklog w, 
                 jira.project p, 
                 jira.issuetype t, 
                 jira.component c, 
                 (SELECT source_node_id, source_node_entity
                       ,max(sink_node_id) as sink_node_id
                    FROM jira.nodeassociation
                  GROUP BY source_node_id, source_node_entity) na, 
                 jira.cwd_user u

WHERE           w.issueid=j.id 
AND             j.project=p.id 
AND             na.source_node_id = j.id 
AND             na.source_node_entity = 'Issue' 
AND             na.sink_node_id=c.id 
AND             t.id=j.issuetype 
And             w.author= u.lower_user_name
AND             w.author in ( select distinct author 
                                from jira.worklog 
                               where author 
                                     in (select distinct lower_user_name 
                                          from jira.cwd_user 
                                         where display_name in ('Ilanas ejemplo')))   
AND             p.pname=  'Area Económica'  
AND             t.pname= 'Peticion'
AND             w.startdate >='01/01/2018' 
AND             w.startdate <='17/10/2018'
```

But bear in mind that this "trick" might generate false data. But if you are in the hurry and not being able to correct erroneous user input you can compare your report with this query by using MIN and MAX aggregate function and make up your mind if it is good enough or not.

Comment: hello i have another doubt. i look that all is ok but sometime the data is no consistent. looking in tables y watch tah sometimes the nodeassociation is empty, so  the following sentence aren't true.    a.source_node_id = j.id 
AND             na.source_node_entity = 'Issue' 
AND             na.sink_node_id=c.id .                                                                             the problem is that in this cases exist w.timeworked bau no c.cname. i want create a "Vacio" c.cname and sum in this c.cname the timewored. Someone any solution?